# Distance for fuzzy c-mean clustering

Tags: clustering, distance

Fuzzy c-means clustering will use Euclidean distance and the mean square error, or Manhattan distance and the mean absolute error. Which of those distance measures you should use for fuzzy c-means, and why?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Are you asking *which* of those distance measures you should use for fuzzy c-means? Or are you asking *why* those are the possibilities? Or something else?

Comment: which of those distance measures you should use for fuzzy c-means?

Answer (score 1):

Like k-means, the use of any other distance than **squared Euclidean** (except for a few Bregman divergences) is questionable.

The *mean* does not minimize arbitrary distance functions. It does minimize squared errors, thus squared Euclidean (= sum of squared errors) is consistent with this step.